# Delphi main form goes behind other applications after disable/enable

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl

I have some vcl mdi application and I need to make some work inside it and show another not modal form of progress above it. And because this progress form is updated from some thread and have some buttons on it (to cancel operation), I update progress with application.ProcessMessages. During this process I need to disable all main form controls. I do it in this way:

```
MainForm.enabled := false;
... do some work here, update progress ...
MainForm.enabled := true;
```

Though, after this my main form goes under other windows applications which is not cool. If I remove this two lines enabled/disabled - it stays on top as it should be.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Use a modal form

Comment: For some reason I prefer not to use modal form. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to determine that reason. Then try and learn what ShowModal does. Then try to recognize how that reason apply to both, that's ShowModal and disabling main form. Then try to come up with the differences of both (hint: the VCL does a proper job of it).

Comment: If you are going to disable the main form then you may as well use a modal form form progress. Doing so will disable the main form properly.

Comment: Modal form shown with ShowModal waits until that function returns back to main process. My progress form is called from many different places and does not do anything except showing progress. All job is done in that other places. That's why I do not use modal form.

Comment: I tried to reproduce steps in ShowModal - but without success (except making progress form modal), still have effect when main window goes behind others and returns back.

Comment: You can use a modal form. I know I do to solve the exact same problem. You just need to arrange that the modal form kicks off the work task.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `BringTofront` works. It can be before or after setting `enabled` to be `true`.

```
MainForm.enabled := false;
// ... do some work here, update progress ...
MainForm.enabled := true;
MainForm.BringTofront;
```

or

```
MainForm.enabled := false;
// ... do some work here, update progress ...
MainForm.BringTofront;
MainForm.enabled := true;
```

**Edit**:
As commented below, with the above code the main form will go behind the others before it becomes focused. This happens in Delphi 7 but seems not in Delphi 2009.

When the current active form is closed or becomes hidden, Delphi tries to switch to the main form. However, if the main form is disabled, Delphi cannot activate it and will move it to the back. The solution is fairly simple, just set `Enabled` to be `true` right before hiding or freeing the other form. There is no need to call `BringTofront`.

```
MainForm.enabled := false;
ProgressForm.Show;  // Or Application.CreateForm(...)
// ... do some work here, update progress ...
MainForm.enabled := true;
ProgressForm.Hide;  // Or ProgressForm.Free;
```

**Edit**:
Here is the Delphi code that causes this behavior:

```
procedure TCustomForm.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
  ....
begin
  ....
      NewActiveWindow := 0;
      if (GetActiveWindow = Handle) and not IsIconic(Handle) then
        NewActiveWindow := FindTopMostWindow(Handle);
      if NewActiveWindow <> 0 then
      begin
        SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW or
          SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        SetActiveWindow(NewActiveWindow);
      end else
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
  ....
end;
```

another fix is to handle the `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED` message of the second form:

```
procedure CMSHOWINGCHANGED(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;

procedure TProgressForm.CMSHOWINGCHANGED(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if not visible then
     Application.MainForm.Enabled := True;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: It works, but... main form first goes behind other windows and then returns back which looks not good. Same effect with Windows.SetActiveWindow(handle);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks I found the solution. PopupMode of the progress form set to pmAuto. Main form stays on top in this case.

It works in this way:

```
procedure TMainForm.DoSomenthing;
begin
  enabled := false;
  try
    // open progress form
    Include(ProgressFrm.FFormState, fsModal);
    ProgressFrm.Show;

    .... do something, update progress ....

    // close progress form
    ProgressFrm.Hide;
    Exclude(ProgressFrm.FFormState, fsModal);
  finally
    enabled := true;
    BringToFront;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Simply move `ProgressFrm.Hide;` after `enabled := true;` should work.